# How to remove variations in the y axis of template matching (opencv)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

With the below function, the coords returned will be slightly different each time, because the template matching found the same template a few pixels up or down. Increasing threshold  does not help, as it will simply not find anything if higher.
How could I make it always return the same coordinates after finding the template, without this little variation in the y axis (I don't care about the precision of the x axis)?

The function, which runs inside an infinite loop in this:

---

```
def fishing_region(img_gray, region_template_gray, w, h): # w, h is how wide and high is the template

    region_detected = False

    green_bar_region = img_gray[y-5:470+y, 347+x:488+x]

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, region_template_gray, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    threshold = 0.65

    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):

        x1, y1 = pt[0], pt[1]         # top-left corner
        x2, y2 = pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h # bottom-right corner

        coords_list = [y1, y2, x1 + 55, x2 - 35]

        region_detected = True
        print("Region detected")
        break  # only finds the template 1 time per function call

    if not region_detected:
        print("No region")

    return region_detected, coords_list
```

EDIT: Here is the rectangle draw with the coordinates and the template: [album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1D5I.jpg).
Also, would masking the template image, removing the parts that changes colors, be possible?

Comment: Can you provide some sample images as well ?

Comment: Can you post a source image and two output examples?

Comment: @zdar Added an album. Can you check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require only one matching region per image, using the `cv2.minMaxLoc()` function on `res` will find the global maximum. This will be stable for a given image and template.

To replicate the threshold you have, you could use the following psuedocode:

```
~, maxVal, ~, maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
if (maxVal > thresh):
 rest_of_function()
```

Comment: But can I use `cv2.minMaxLoc()` with threshold?

Comment: Yes, see my edit. The function returns the value (as the second return argument) and location (as the fourth) of the maximum values in the matrix. You can condition on the maximum value being above your threshold.